# Pick first three consonants and if duplicate, pick the next consonant in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of stores in one column. I want to make a special code for those stores in the next column.

The rule for that code is that I need the first three consonants of that store. For example, if a store name is Apple, the code would be PPL. Similar if the store is Electronics, the code would be LCT

In cases where the first three consonants of the stores are similar to another store, I would want it to pick the first two consonants and then take the fourth consonant for the one where the duplicate occurs. In cases where the first two are the same and the fourth consonant is similar too, then we keep the first two and select the fifth consonant and so on.

[example table with solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLSRl.png)

Currently I am able to extract the first three consonants but not sure how to deal with the duplicate codes, any ideas how I can achieve this on google sheets?

My current formula is

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A2),"a",""),"e",""),"i",""),"o",""),"u","")
```

Currently I am able to extract the first three consonants but not sure how to deal with the duplicate codes, any ideas how I can achieve this on google sheets?

Answer (score 2):

You could try making a list of the strings formed by taking the first two consonants and one other consonant, then finding the first one that hasn't been used:

```
=ArrayFormula(let(cons,regexreplace(A2,"(?i)[aeiou ]",""),
list,map(sequence(len(cons)-2,1,3),lambda(c,left(cons,2)&mid(cons,c,1))),
upper(xlookup(false,isnumber(match(list,C$1:C1,0)),list))))
```

This is just a pull-down formula nothing fancy.

[image]

I could have used countif, a bit shorter:

```
=ArrayFormula(let(cons,regexreplace(A2,"(?i)[aeiou ]",""),
list,map(sequence(len(cons)-2,1,3),lambda(c,left(cons,2)&mid(cons,c,1))),
upper(xlookup(0,countif(C$1:C1,list),list))))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion:

It seems it is more complicated than expected, I am not sure if it would be possible using formula.
However as an alternative, you can use apps script. Try the code below as a custom formula.

**Try:**

```
function getCode(range) {
  var stores = range
  var codes = []

  for (let i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
    var consonants = stores[i][0].match(/[^aeiou]/ig).join("").replace(/ /gm, "").toUpperCase();
    var firstThree = consonants.substr(0, 3);

    var counter = 2
    while (codes.flat().includes(firstThree)) {
      var firstTwo = consonants.substr(0, 2)
      var third = consonants.substr(counter++, 1)
      firstThree = firstTwo.concat(third)
    }
    codes.push([firstThree])
  }
  return codes
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

To use the formula just use the function name and use the range as input.